Method App\Livewire\Post\Comment::emit does not exist
I use the Livewire framework in my Laravel, I created a comment feature, I want when I comment the screen will automatically scroll to the comment via the ID that I inserted using JavaScript but when I make a comment it should automatically scroll down but instead it appears
error message "Method App\Livewire\Post\Comment::emit does not exist."
Please help me
 public function store()
    {
        $this->validate(["body" => "required"]);
        $comment = ModelsComment::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            "article_id" => $this->article->id,
            "body" => $this->body
        ]);

        if($comment){
            $this->emit('commentStored', $comment->id);
            $this->body = null; 
        } else {
            session()->flash('danger', 'Komentar gagal Ditambahkan!!');
            return redirect()->route('data', $this->article->slug);
        }
    }

$this->emit('commentStored', $comment->id);
I searched on any site but no one discussed this error

Is your class extending from the Livewire Component class?

Hi there! Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow. Please add the full stack trace for the error and/or the code that generates the error.

I suppose you are using Livewire 3.
In this version the emit() and dispatchBrowserEvent() methods have been unified into the dispatch() method.
The parameter must now be identified with the name assigned in the event handler:
$this->dispatch('commentStored', commentId: $comment->id);

namespace App\Livewire;
use Livewire\Attributes\On; // <~~~ note this

class someClass extends Component
{
    ....

    #[On('commentStored')] // <~~~ and this
    public function methodThatHandlesTheEvent(int $commentId) // <~~~ parameter name
    {
       dd ($commentId);
    }

    ....



People really need to start stating their version, and for newbies, what guide they've been following, because this whole thread probably wouldn't have been created if OP noticed the tutorial was for V2 and was using V3.

In my case, upgrading from livewire 2.x to 3.x is easy:

$this->emit('updateHeaderOfForm');     //livewire 2.x

//is now

$this->dispatch('updateHeaderOfForm');  //livewire 3.x

NO MORE CHANGES

The solution is in the livewire documentation linked in the first answer of this post, more precisely at https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#events
